# Change count of tabs in 'case' keyword on emacs in c++ mode

Tags: c++, emacs, coding-style

I changed the coding style to `BSD` on emacs and now it look like this:

```
switch(a)
{
 case TYPEvar:
    return x(node);
}
```

I want to add a tab before `case`, like this:

```
switch(node->type)
{
  case TYPEvar:
       return walk(node);
}
```

What do I need change in .emacs? I tried (I don't do emacs lisp) change `tab-width` in:

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 2
          tab-width 2
          indent-tabs-mode t)
```

But it changed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this only for the current buffer go to the line containing `case` and do <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd>, it will prompt you for syntactic symbol whose indentation you want to change enter/select `case-label` (this is selected by default). Then enter the value of indentation, enter your desired indentation.

The above sets the indentation for the current buffer. To set indentation for all the buffers you can use `c-mode-common-hook` as follows

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
                                (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(case-label . 2))))
```

Comment: Excatly that. Thanks! Also, can I apply this change to auto indent files that aren't already indented with this new style?

Comment: You can write some elisp code . Like `(setq files '("~/test.c"))

(dolist (file files)
  (with-current-buffer (find-file file)
    (mark-whole-buffer)
    (indent-for-tab-command)
    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer)))`

should do the job where `files` is the list of files you want to indent. Be CAREFUL though I have not tested it!